# Import as data.frame numeric and select json variables

Tags: r, json

I have a .csv file with two numeric columns and one in json format. I want to import both numeric columns as well as some variables from the json column. The json column has hundreds of variables, many of which have the same name, and I am only interested in a few: is there a way to import a select number of variables from json using their number placement?

```
 address    |  zip  |  response
 102 N8 st    11248   {"Building Lat": "74.91", "Lon": "31.21", "Front Lat": "75.93", "Lon": "32.20"}
 76 Hope st   14258   {"Building Lat": "75.82", "Lon": "29.18", "Front Lat": "76.89", "Lon": "28.12"}
```

When I import as read_csv, I get a tibble that looks something like the above example: imagine I want to import as data.frame in R both address and zip, as well as the fist two variables from the json response variable (Building Lat and Lon).

This is somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41152990/json-parsing-a-single-column-within-a-data-frame?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but could not replicate that answer in this example. I have tried Jsonlite package, but could not get around it.

Comment: That's not a CSV formatted file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
require(jsonlite)

df <- data.frame(address = c("102 N8 st", "76 Hope st"),
                 zip = c(11248, 14258),
                 response = c('{"Building Lat": "74.91", "Lon": "31.21", "Front Lat": "75.93", "Lon": "32.20"}',
                              '{"Building Lat": "75.82", "Lon": "29.18", "Front Lat": "76.89", "Lon": "28.12"}'),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

x1 <- sapply(df$response, FUN = function(x) {as.numeric(fromJSON(x)[[1]])})
x2 <- sapply(df$response, FUN = function(x) {as.numeric(fromJSON(x)[[2]])})

names(x1) <- NULL
names(x2) <- NULL

new_df <- data.frame(address = df$address,
                     zip = df$zip,
                     x1 = x1, 
                     x2 = x2)
```

Comment: That does exactly what I want for the small example I showed there, thanks! But when I try to do this for complete database I get the following error, any idea what that T/F I am missing is?  
Error in if (is.character(txt) && length(txt) == 1 && nchar(txt, type = "bytes") <  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: You probably have some JSON cells that are missing or not well-formatted. Try to filter them first. Try `df %>% filter(!is.na(response))` for example.